# Clear Android default Browser history in marshmallow not working,

Tags: android

code Used

```
     try {
            ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();

            Browser.clearHistory(cR);
            Browser.clearSearches(cR);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The history get cleared till Android Kitkat but from Lollypop and marshmallow it is not getting cleared..
history not cleared after executing code above, is there anything i am missing??

Comment: Those methods were removed from the Android SDK with API Level 23, IIRC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so what is the another way to clear Android default browser history in In API Level 23 and above?

Comment: Only if a specific browser has exposed a specific API for it that you use.